# React Router DOM useNavigate function not redirecting the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

The code below should redirect the registration screen to the login screen when the user to register. Registration in the database is being done, however, when submitting the form, it still displays the error message "Registration failed!" and does not redirect to the login screen.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import './Register.css';
import axios from 'axios';

function Register() {
    const [firstname, setFirstname] = useState('');
    const [lastname, setLastname] = useState('');
    const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');
    const navigate = useNavigate(); // Added useNavigate hook

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        try {
            const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:3001/register', {
                firstname,
                lastname,
                username,
                email,
                password,
            });

            if (response.data.success) {
                navigate("/login"); // Redirect to login screen on success
            } else {
                setErrorMessage(response.data.message || 'Registration failed!');
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error during registration:', error);
            setErrorMessage('An unexpected error occurred. Please try again later.');
        }
    };

        return (
            <div className="register-container">
                <h1>Registro</h1>
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        name="firstname"
                        placeholder="First Name"
                        value={firstname}
                        onChange={(e) => { setFirstname(e.target.value) }}
                    />
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        name="lastname"
                        placeholder="Last Name"
                        value={lastname}
                        onChange={(e) => { setLastname(e.target.value) }}
                    />
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        name="username"
                        placeholder="Username"
                        value={username}
                        onChange={(e) => { setUsername(e.target.value) }}
                    />
                    <input
                        type="email"
                        name="email"
                        placeholder="E-mail"
                        value={email}
                        onChange={(e) => { setEmail(e.target.value) }}
                    />
                    <input
                        type="password"
                        name="password"
                        placeholder="Password"
                        value={password}
                        onChange={(e) => { setPassword(e.target.value) }}
                    />
                    <input type="submit" value="Register" />
                </form>
                {errorMessage && <p>{errorMessage}</p>}
                <p>
                    You have an account? <Link to="/login">login here</Link>
                </p>
            </div>
        );
    };

export default Register;
```

I read in a post here on Stack that using useNavigate within the Render function would solve the problem, however, it still isn't working, could you help me?

Comment: if you console.log(response.data.success) is everything OK?

Comment: it simply doesn't display anything on the log when i submit the form, even if i console.log(response.data.success)  :/

Comment: and if you console.log(response), this if the post is correct it should return something

Comment: displays "{data: 'Account created successfully!', status: 200, statusText: 'OK', headers: AxiosHeaders, config: {…}, …}" and the data is beign sent to the database

Comment: is your app wrapped correctly with BrowserRouter?

Comment: yes it's, and when i try to access the login route with "link" for example, access normally

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `response.data` doesn't have such property `success`.
If you have power over the server, do you send response like so?

```
res.status(200).json({success: true, newUser: newUser})
```

Comment: Yes, the response is "{data: 'Account created successfully!', status: 200, statusText: 'OK', headers: AxiosHeaders, config: {…}, …}" but i don't know how this can't affect the hook useNavigate, considering that the conditional "if" defines when the registration is successful, "useNavigate" is triggered and the page is redirected to the login screen, it's working but it's not affecting the hook "navigate"

Comment: i may not have been clear, but the useNavigate isn't working despite the registration is